# speed up parsing in html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, web-crawler, google-local-search

This is a method I use to grab certain tags with the html agility pack.  I use this method to do rankings with google local.  It seems to take quite a bit of time and be memory intensive, does anyone have any suggestions to make it better?

```
 private void findGoogleLocal(HtmlNode node) {

     String   name        = String.Empty;
     // 
     // ----------------------------------------
     if (node.Attributes["id"] != null) {

       if (node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString().Contains("panel_") &&   node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString() != "panel__")
        {
        GoogleLocalResults.Add(new Result(URLGoogleLocal, Listing, node, SearchEngine.Google, SearchType.Local, ResultType.GooglePlaces));
        }
    }

    if (node.HasChildNodes) {
      foreach (HtmlNode children in node.ChildNodes)  {
        findGoogleLocal(children);
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does this method have to be recursive? Just get all the nodes in one go (example using the Linq support in HAP):

```
var results = node.Descendants()
                  .Where(x=> x.Attributes["id"]!= null && 
                             x.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("panel_") &&  
                             x.Attributes["id"].Value!= "panel__")
                  .Select( x=> new Result(URLGoogleLocal, Listing, x, SearchEngine.Google, SearchType.Local, ResultType.GooglePlaces));
```

Comment: thank you works perfect!                                      foreach(Result x in results)
          {
              GoogleLocalResults.Add(x);
          }

Comment: You can even make this simpler, as HtmlNode has an Id property which is available by default. So x.Id.Contains("panel_") && !x.Id == "panel__" and no need to check x.Id == null either.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add another clean, simple and fast solution: using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

```
var results = node
                .SelectNodes(@"//*[contains(@id, 'panel_') and @id != 'panel__']")
                .Select(x => new Result(URLGoogleLocal, Listing, x, SearchEngine.Google, SearchType.Local, ResultType.GooglePlaces));
foreach (var result in results)
    GoogleLocalResults.Add(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fizzler: CSS selector engine for HAP

http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/